Declaration of dynamic array before getting array length
In dynamic allocation of arrays at runtime, when the array is declared before getting the array length, I encountered a behavior that could not explain.
In the following code, the user provides the length of the array, say 5 and then provides five space-separated numbers as input, say 4 3 7 2 1. By printing length after the for loop we see that it changes.
Here is the code.
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int length;
    int ar[length];

    cout << "Enter the length of array: ";
     
    cin >> length;
    cout << "--- length before: " << length << endl;

    cout << "Provide " << length << " integer values separated by space and then press Enter." << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        cin >> ar[i];
        cout << "i: " << i << " - ar[i]: " << ar[i] << endl;
    }
        
    cout << "--- length after: " << length << endl;
    

    return 0;
}

And the output with input 4 3 7 2 1:
Enter the length of array: 5
--- length before: 5
Provide 5 integer values separated by space and then press Enter.
4 3 7 2 1
i: 0 - ar[i]: 4
i: 3 - ar[i]: -1
--- length after: 4

After trying out different inputs, I found that length is changed to the first input integer, here 4. The value of i in the loop also jumps based on the given input.
I know the array has to be declared after cin but any explanations for the behavior?

It's Undefined Behaviour. There is no explanation for what happens, compiler can do absolutely anything with such code.

Unless this is an academic exercise (homework) don't manually allocate arrays.  Instead use a std::vector.

For some reason newbies always assume this will work, but it doesn't. The length of ar is fixed when you create it (and length is uninitialized at that time). The array will not track length and update its length dynamically.

@HolyBlackCat OP knows that, see last sentence.

Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard? Use std::vector instead.

And uninitialized local variables, like length, will have an indeterminate value. Using indeterminate values, in any way, leads to undefined behavior.

Undefined behaviour is undefined.

If you are curious about how to use a vector instead (like you should), here's an example.

Consistency of UB for a fixed compiler and Why is the phrase UB means anything can happen is true

It seems to be a common belief among newbies that any program you write, and which compiles must have some defined behaviour, whatever that might be. There are languages that come close to that (Java for example) but C++ is a long long way away from that condition. You can easily write trivial C++ programs whose behaviour is undefined. When such programs run the compiler can (and will) make them behave in all sorts of strange and unpredictable ways. This is largely done for efficiency reasons, but it is one of the things that make C++ hard. Such is the price we pay for being C++ programmers.

@NathanOliver Yes, it is somehow an exercise and I was playing around with it to see the behavior. I consider it at as undefined behavior.

I consider it at as undefined behavior.  There is not much point in trying to understand the behavior of code that has undefined behavior.  If you are unlucky, it may appear to work.  (Which appears to be the case you are seeing here.)  If you are lucky, it will crash.  Possibly "it works on my machine", but fails spectacularly when giving a demo to your boss.

"it is somehow an exercise". That's the wrong type of exercise. VLA is not standard C++. Just don't do it. If you are forced to avoid std::vector then at least try new[]+delete[]. But that one is not good C++ either; it's just to pass the course you have with an idiot professor.


After trying out different inputs, I found that length is changed to the first input integer, here 4.

What likely happens is that length happens to be zero (keep in mind that reading it is UB due to it being uninitialized, and that's not counting variable-length arrays not being a part of standard C++).
ar then becomes a zero-length array, and accessing a[0] is out of bounds (which is again UB). Apparently length happens to be right after the array in the stack, so it gets overwritten.
